# Book recommendation : Combinatorics book Olympiad

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, book-recommendation

Im a 10th grader and i want to learn combinatorics. I donot have a mentor and planning to self study it. Im interested in solving Olympiad probelms and maybe participate as well. I want a book that explains combinatorics to me like a kid!

I know a bit of graph theory and a little bit of generating functions. I would love to learn recurrence relations. I would love to see a book within this topics as well. Thanks!

Comment: What is your current level? Are you able to solve IMO shortlisted problems or maybe do a good amount of approach?

Comment: I can solve 1's and 2's from geometry. Some basic problems from Number Theory. I just started like 2 months ago to solve problems. It's basically long way to go!

Comment: @KriteshDhakal perhaps this might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781790/book-recommendation-olympiad-combinatorics-book  . The user who asked this question also is pretty new to combinatorics so the recommendations might be helpful to you ..

Comment: @Raheel thanks i will cheeck it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Principles of Combinatorics](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Principles_And_Techniques_In_Combinatori.html?id=jBrtCgAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) by Chen Chuang Chong quite easy to read and very explicitly presented. It also includes a number of problems from IMO, Putnam and Regional Olympiads.

Comment: Thank you! Ill check it out!