# A child has $5$ locomotive and $20$ different toy coaches (Train carriage).Then how many Different trains are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A child has $5$ locomotive and $20$ different toy coaches (Train carriage). In how many ways he can make different trains, If only locomotive can also be considered as train.

**My approach:**

If add first coach there are 5 choice for me and now if add second boogey then I've 6 choice and so on,
so my answer will be $5 \cdot 6\cdot7\cdot ...\cdot 24$.

Now I'll add $5$ to above calculated answer as only locomotive alone can be considered as train.

**But given answer is only $5\cdot6\cdot7...\cdot24$**

Why they have not added $5$?

Is above solution correct?

Comment: What are "boogies"?

Comment: Can multiple locomotives be put on the train? After all real trains have them quite often. Assuming the answer is no, I don't see this calculation at all. Why out of 20 boogies do you only have five choices for the first? Why of the 19 remaining boogies would you only have 6 choices for the second? I would calculate $5$ choices for engine, and $\sum_{n=0}^{20}\frac {20!}{n!}$ choices for the added boogies, for $5\cdot 20!\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{20}\frac 1 {n!}\approx 5\cdot 20!\cdot e$ choices overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a much simpler version of the problem.  Say we have two locomotives and two coaches.  Let's name the locomotives $L_1$ and $L_2$ and the coaches $C_1$ and $C_2$.

We have two ways to append coach $C_1$ to a locomotive.  Once we have placed coach $C_1$, there are three ways to place coach $C_2$.  We can append it to the other locomotive, place it behind coach $C_1$, or place it between the locomotive to which coach $C_1$ is attached and coach $C_1$.  This gives $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ possible arrangements.  They are:

$(L_1C_1C_2, L_2)$

$(L_1C_1, L_2C_2)$

$(L_1C_2C_1, L_2)$

$(L_1, L_2C_1C_2)$

$(L_1C_2, L_2C_1)$

$(L_1, L_2C_2C_1)$

Notice that these arrangements include the cases in which a locomotive is by itself.  There is no need to handle the cases of an isolated locomotive separately since choosing a position for each coach completely determines the arrangement of the cars on each train.

Comment: Thanks, Where can i learn more about combinatorics. I can do some basic problem. I need to learn about partition, generating function, and some simple combinatorics problem too. **How did you learn all these?.** Can you suggest me some book which i should follow in sequence.

Comment: Also combinatorics problem involving $f(f(x))=x$ from set $A\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ to $A\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Comment: The first book I read was *Mathematics of Choice* by Ivan Niven, but it is a bit basic for your purposes.  It sounds like what you need is an advanced undergraduate text on combinatorics such as Miklos Bona's *A Walk Through Combinatorics*.    See recommendations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781790/book-recommendation-olympiad-combinatorics-book), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator).