# Textbooks for math contests apart from AoPs

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am looking for textbooks on math contests that give the theory associated with the topics
(such as graph theory,geometry,Trig,combinatorics,etc) before giving a large volley of problems to solve(apart from AoPs). I am a high schooler and  complete beginner to these.
Is there a textbook that discusses theory as good as Arthur Engel has done for problem solving in the book **Problem Solving Strategies**?

Comment: USA Olympiad preperation books like 102 combinatorial problems and 104 Number Theory problems by Titu Andrescu may be helpful.

Comment: You can also view this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781790/book-recommendation-olympiad-combinatorics-book/3782841#3782841) for a comprehensive list of materials for olympiad combinatorics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the books I recommend every mathlete from my personal experience:

**Geometry and Trigonometry:**

- [Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883858398) by Evan Chen: This is the most recommended book for Olympiad geometry. The book goes through many important concepts and also gives insights of solving problems.
- [Geometry Revisited](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0883856190) by H.S.M Coxeter: An awesome classic. Some IMO medalists still recommend this book above EGMO.
- [Geometry Unbound](https://archive.org/details/flooved3488/mode/2up) by Kiran S. Kedlaya: If you've completed all necessary concepts in geometry and want to solve some good problems, this is the book you're looking for.
- [103 Trigonometry Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817643346) by Titu Andreescu: A good problem book for Olympiad trigonometry.

**Inequalities:**

- [Secrets in Inequalities volume 1 and 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/7560346006) by Pham Kim Hung: The best inequality book. But not recommended for a complete beginner as the problems here are very high level.
- [Inequalities a Mathematical Olympiad Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3034600496) by Rogelio: A good book for Olympiad inequalities. Also suitable for beginners.
- [Inequalities- Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642237916) by Cvetcovski (suggested by Dr. Mathva)
- [Inequalities an Approach Through Problems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789811087325) by B J Venkatachala

**Functional Equations:**

- [Functional Equations and How to Solve Them](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387345396) by Christopher G. Small
- [Functional Equations a Problem Solving Approach](https://www.amazon.in/Functional-Equations-Problem-Solving-Approach/dp/8172862652) by B J Venkatachala

**Algebra:**

- [101 Problems in Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/187642012X) by Titu Andreescu

**Number Theory:**

- [Modern Olympiad Number Theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2344755) by Aditya Khurmi (suggested by Dr. Mathva)
- [Olympiad Number Theory Through Challenging Problems](https://www.academia.edu/32278024/Olympiad_Number_Theory_Olympiad_Number_Theory_Through_Challenging_Problems) by Justin Stevens
- [Number Theory a Problem Solving Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/081763245X) by Titu Andreescu
- [104 Number Theory Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817645276) by Titu Andreescu

**Combinatorics:**

- [A Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817642889) by Titu Andreescu
- [102 Combinatorial Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817643176) by Titu Andreescu
- [Problem Solving Methods in Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3034805969) by Pablo Soberón
- [Graph Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814271128) by Xiong Bin

**Problem Solving:**

- [The Arts and Crafts of Problem Solving](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471135712) by Paul Zeitz: The best problem solving book. Also a good resource for recreational mathematics problems.
- [How to Solve It](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069111966X) by George Polya.

Again, I mention these are my recommendations. Others suggestion may differ from this (you may add your suggestions in the comments). And there might be some books I forgot to include. May your math journey be enjoyable. Happy problem solving!

Comment: I would add "A walk through combinatorics: an introduction to enumeration and graph theory". While it's not made for olympiad problems as far as I can tell. It covers much of the same material while still managing to be engaging and interesting.

Comment: Great recommendations!! There are only two other books I find essential when it comes to contest Math. “Inequialities”, by Cvetkovski, Zdravko (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642237911) and Khurmi’s “Modern Olympiad Number Theory” (which can be found for free on aops: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2344755). The first book does not only cover the most common and helpful techniques, but also gives an insight on more complex and advanced ones; from the second book, I will only say that it has been compared to Evan Chen’s work, but in NT ;)

Comment: Also, Evan Chen has a nice list of recommendations in his webpage which include both books and other resources online (such as helpful handouts): https://web.evanchen.cc/recommend.html

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I've read the first book. The book was good but I forgot to include that. The second book, I never knew existed. I read first few pages of the book and I think it's worth comparing to EGMO. Thanks for your suggestion, especially the second one. I've added both the in my list.